# a problem in linear algebra about the chain of invariant subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

I met such a linear algebra problem in a book and had no idea:

Let $X$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ (may not be finite dimensional). Let $T$ be a linear operator over $X$. Suppose $X \cong \operatorname{ker}\left(T^{n}\right) \oplus i m\left(T^{n}\right)$. Can we conclude $\operatorname{ker}\left(T^{n}\right)=\operatorname{ker}\left(T^{n+1}\right), i m\left(T^{n}\right)=i m\left(T^{n+1}\right)$?

Can anyone give me some hint? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$${\rm im}(T^{n})=T^n(X)=T^n({\rm ker}(T^n)\oplus {\rm im}(T^n))=T^n({\rm im}(T^n))={\rm im}(T^{2n})\subseteq {\rm im}(T^{n+1})\subseteq {\rm im}(T^{n})$$

$$
{\rm ker}(T^{n+1})\subseteq {\rm ker}(T^{2n})=(T^n)^{-1}({\rm ker}(T^{n}))
=(T^n)^{-1}({\rm ker}(T^{n})\cap {\rm im}(T^n))=(T^n)^{-1}(0)
={\rm ker}(T^{n})\subseteq{\rm ker}(T^{n+1})
$$

Here $(T^n)^{-1}$ denotes the preimage operation of $T^n$ on sets, not the inverse of $T^n$.